# how to filter repeated rows from a joining more than two tables

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures

i have an event table that have one to many relation with more than two (Ticket, Guest, Sponsor) tables. they are related with the event table with a foreign key constraint.
Now when i use left join using(EVENT_ID) i get records repeating multiple times until the largest table result set rows are reached for other tables record

is their a way to get make those records from other tables null.
this are my tables i only showed columns that are related with my question in this example for space and simplicity

```
    CREATE TABLE event(
                EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
              ) ;      
  CREATE TABLE eventSponsor (
                  SPONSOR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                  EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
                  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                 FOREIGN KEY fk_key(EVENT_ID)
                 REFERENCES event(EVENT_ID)
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                )ENGINE=InnoDB;
  CREATE TABLE eventGuest(
                GUEST_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY fk_guest(EVENT_ID)
                REFERENCES event(EVENT_ID)
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                )ENGINE=InnoDB;

         CREATE TABLE eventTicket(
                TICKET_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
                name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,                                      
               FOREIGN KEY fk_ticket(EVENT_ID) 
               REFERENCES event(EVENT_ID)
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

this is my join

```
    SELECT `event`.`EVENT_ID`, `event`.`name` AS `eventName`, `eventGuest`.`GUEST_ID` `eventGuest`.`first_name` AS 'guestName',`eventSponsor`.`SPONSOR_ID`, `eventSponsor`.`name` AS 'sponsorName', `eventTicket`.`TICKET_ID`, `eventTicket`.`name` AS 'ticketName'
  FROM `event`
    RIGHT JOIN `eventTicket` USING(`EVENT_ID`)
    LEFT JOIN `eventGuest` USING(`EVENT_ID`)
    LEFT JOIN `eventSponsor` USING(`EVENT_ID`)
    WHERE `event`.`EVENT_ID` = in_eventId;
```

and i get a result of

```
EVENT_ID |eventName | GUEST_ID | guestName | SPONSOR_ID | sponsorName | TICKET_ID | ticketName
   1     | event1  |   1  | guest1    |   1        | sponsor1    |   1  | ticket1  |
   1     | event1  |   2  | guest2    |   2        | sponsor2    |   2  | ticket2  | 
   1     | event1  |   1  | guest1    |   3        | sponsor3    |   3  | ticket3  |
   1     |  event1 |   2  | guest2    |   1        | sponsor1    |   4  | ticket4  |
```

see since there are 4 tickets associated with that event but only 2 guests and 3 sponsors their record repeats until they are equal with ticket row but.
what i want was to get something like this

```
EVENT_ID |eventName | GUEST_ID | guestName | SPONSOR_ID | sponsorName | TICKET_ID | ticketName
   1     | event1  |   1  | guest1    |   1        | sponsor1    |   1  | ticket1  |
   1     | event1  |   2  | guest2    |   2        | sponsor2    |   2  | ticket2  | 
   1     | event1  |   null  | null   |   3        | sponsor3    |   3  | ticket3  |
   1     |  event1 |   null  | null   |   null     | null        |   4  | ticket4  |
```

is it possible to twick my join and get this result or is that the default. if it is what do you suggest a workaround for this. FYI i'm writing this SQL inside a stored procedure.
thank you in advance.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: okay sorry i haven't read that recommendation before now.

Comment: So, there is sample data on sqlfiddle ?